# How Do I pair up the Names with corresponding ID Numbers?

Tags: c#

I do not get what code I need to make the Names pair up with the corresponding ID Numbers. Any help would be appreciated thanks

```
class Program
{
    struct StudentID
    {
        public int idNumber;
        public string name;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StudentID[] StudentInfo = new StudentID[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < StudentInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter ID Number: ");
            StudentInfo[i].idNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
            StudentInfo[i].name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < StudentInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < StudentInfo.Length; j++)
            {

               if (StudentInfo[i].idNumber < StudentInfo[j].idNumber)
                {
                    temp = StudentInfo[i].idNumber;

                    StudentInfo[i].idNumber = StudentInfo[j].idNumber;

                    StudentInfo[j].idNumber = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.Write("Student ID Sorted with Corresponding Name: ");

        for ( int i =0; i < StudentInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nStudent ID : {0} ", StudentInfo[i].idNumber);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only swapping the ID number in each entry. You want to swap the whole entry.

```
if (StudentInfo[i].idNumber < StudentInfo[j].idNumber)
{
    var temp = StudentInfo[i];
    StudentInfo[i] = StudentInfo[j];
    StudentInfo[j] = temp;
}
```